# How can I integrate open source licenses, such as MIT, into my own open source project when my code is unlicensed?

Tags: licensing, relicensing, multi-licensing

I want to use a portion of an existing project that is licensed under [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT). MIT seems to state that I must include their license in my work, but I don't want to use any license for my own work (i.e. unlicensed). Merely copying their license into my project makes it look like they wrote my entire project instead of just a portion of it.

What is the correct way to integrate someone else's open source license into my project such that I am compliant with the requirements of their license, acknowledging their contribution, but remain able to license my own project a different way, including without explicitly putting a license on it?

Comment: What do you mean with "unlicensing your work"? Do you mean putting it under the [unlicense](http://unlicense.org/) or not putting an explicit license on it?

Comment: If your work is published without a licence of any kind, it's not open source.

Comment: I mean not explicitly putting a license on it.

Comment: If can not be (Open Source or Free Software) and be un-licenced. The licence is the mechanism to make it Open Source or Free Software. Please read the definitions (start with the [free software definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) it is easier).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Nothing in the link you cited says that software must be licensed to be open source or free software. I see no reason, for example, software in the public domain wouldn't qualify.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are correct (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#/media/File:Categories_of_free_and_nonfree_software.svg), but trouble is public domain is not recognised everywhere. And by default an article is copyright. It has been recommended that if you want to put it in the public domain, that you use creative commons zero licence CC0. I do not recommend all creative commons licences (the not commercial are not Free or Open source, and could have problems).

Answer (score 1):

The MIT requirement is no problem for you.  Simply include the MIT license in the code that you got under the MIT license.  That doesn't affect your own code.

If you don't want to license your own work (i.e. not permit anyone to copy or use it), just put an overall statement: "Copyright 2017 Quolonel Questions, all rights reserved."

If you do want others to have unrestricted use of your code, you could apply the Creative Commons CC0 public declaration to your work.

Comment: How should I convey which parts are my work and which are not?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions the best way would be to keep the imported code in a separate file (with the MIT license as a header comment) or a separate folder (if there are several files).

Comment: @Zimmi48 It is impractical to keep files separate as I need to edit the source directly.

Comment: OK, in that case you can keep the license text with a preamble saying this file has been modified, here is the original license, here is a link where you can find the original version.